# WSASendTo Periodically Fails With 10014

Tags: c, windows, winsock, winsock2

I have created a UDP socket, and am trying to send some data over it using `WSASendTo`. This works *sometimes*, but fails sporadically (with WSAEFAULT) and I can't seem to track it down.

First, I setup Winsock2 and create my UDP socket:

```
const char* host = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 10000;

WSADATA wsd = { 0 };

if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd) != 0) {
    return 1;
}

int socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
int family = AF_INET;
int protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

SOCKET sock = WSASocketW(family,
        socktype,
        protocol,
        NULL,
        0,
        WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
```

Then I get the `addr` structure setup with my IP and port:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
int addr_size = sizeof(addr);

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, host, (void*)addr.sin_addr);
addr.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);
```

Finally, I send my data using `WSASendTo`:

```
// `overlapped` and `buf` are both declared at a higher scope so
// that they are available in the completion routine.
WSAOVERLAPPED overlapped = { 0 }
WSABUF buf;


buf.buf = data;
buf.len = size;

char* data = "Hello, World!";
int size = strlen(data);

// Returns -1 here, with WSAGetLastError() == 10014.
ret = WSASendTo(sock,
        &buf,
        1,
        &bytes_sent,
        flags,
        (SOCKADDR*)&addr,
        &addr_size,
        &overlapped,
        SendCompletion);
```

At this point `ret` equals `-1` and a call to `WSAGetLastError` returns either `997` (WSA_IO_PENDING, which I would expect) or, about half the time, `10014` (WSAEFAULT).

According to the documentation, this means that:

> The lpBuffers, lpTo, lpOverlapped, lpNumberOfBytesSent, or lpCompletionRoutine parameters are not part of the user address space, or the lpTo parameter is too small.

I've gone through and verified that these things *appear* to be correct. That is, the addresses seem to be reasonable and the size of things like `lpTo` are correct.

Any idea why this would sometimes fail?

Comment: Is it a straight copy from your program? The first fragment has syntax errors.

Comment: @tgregory No, I took out the extraneous parts. I poorly hand copied the syntax error parts (missing semi-colon, etc). They're fixed now.

Comment: Where is 'overlapped?

Comment: Why is 'buf' on automatic storage?

Comment: It's unusual to see the buffer, OVL block etc, declared as automatic storage since the lifetime of both must extend through to I/O completion notification.

Comment: @MartinJames hm, is it possible that there is a race condition resulting in those variables being declared as auto storage? Like I said, it seems to work *sometimes*.

Comment: If the scope of the OVL,buffer etc. is exited, and so those structs deleted, before the I/O notification is signaled and handled, then there will be problems.  Similarly, if those structs are reloaded for another WSASendTo() call before the I/O notification is signaled and handled, it will be bad.

Comment: @MartinJames So, I never even get to the completion routine. We immediately fail after the `WSASendTo`. I've updated my code so that buf and ovl will remain in scope for the duration of the application. Still hits the 10014 error periodically. Anything else I should look at?

Comment: Your call to `inet_pton()` is wrong, you are passing a bad pointer in the last parameter, so you could be trashing random memory. It should look like `inet_pton(AF_INET, host, &(addr.sin_addr));` instead. Your `(void*)` type-cast is silencing the compiler from complaining about your mistake.

Comment: `&addr_size` is error. must be `addr_size`. if use *c++* he simply say error on your call `WSASendTo`. `int iToLen` not pointer but `int`

Comment: also as general note `WSABUF buf` can be local variable (with local life time) - *Winsock service provider's responsibility to capture the WSABUF structures before returning from this call. This enables applications to build stack-based WSABUF arrays pointed to by the lpBuffers parameter.* - only data buffer itself (in your case this is `"Hello, World!"`) and *lpOverlapped* must be valid for the duration of the overlapped operation. but it anyway must not be *declared at a higher scope* - because completion got pointer to  *lpOverlapped* back.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You were right. I fixed the inet_pton and things seem to be working well. Thank you!

Comment: @RmMm good to know. Is there any benefit to creating WSABUF on the stack for each call to wsasendto?

Comment: @Julio: that is covered by the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741693.aspx): "*If this function is completed in an overlapped manner, it is the Winsock service provider's responsibility to capture the `WSABUF` structures before returning from this call. **This enables applications to build stack-based `WSABUF` arrays pointed to by the `lpBuffers` parameter**.*" So, it is perfectly safe to construct the `WSABUF` on the stack. It is a very lightweight structure